# Modify date in object for aggregate $match query in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this object being sent to a controller in a `node.js` application:

```
var req.body = {
"startDate": {
    "$gte": "1111-11-11T00:00:00.000Z",
    "$lte": "2017-08-17T00:00:00.000Z"
}
}
```

I want a function that will operate on the `startDate` key of this object and give me this output:

```
var req.body = {
"startDate": {
    "$gte": new Date("1111-11-11T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "$lte": new Date("2017-08-17T00:00:00.000Z")
}
}
```

The reason I need this type object is that I'm using `mongoose` to send a query using `aggregate` and `$match` to `mongoDB` using this function:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Activity = mongoose.model('Activity');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

var sendJSONresponse = function(res, status, content) {
res.status(status);
res.json(content);
}; 

module.exports.readOther = function (req, res){

    Activity
        .aggregate([
            {$match: req.body }
        ])
        .exec(function(err, output) {
            sendJSONresponse(res, 200, output);
    });
};
```

`mongoose` requires that the date type `new Date(` be specified and as such, will return no documents with the original object applied. The query that `mongoose` is sending to the server now (formatted for readability) is:

```
Mongoose: activity.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': 
        { 
            startDate: { '$gte': '1111-11-11T00:00:00.000Z', '$lte': '2017-08-17T00:00:00.000Z' }
        }, 
], {})
```

I have tried the following to modify the object, but it just turns it into an actual date, which `mongoose` does not process correctly

```
Object.keys(req.body.startDate).map(function (key) {
    req.body.startDate[key] = eval(new Date( req.body.startDate[key] ));
    return req.body.startDate;
  });
```

Please help me either with the function requested or suggest another approach that would allow me to query a date range.

Comment: Can you not have your client send the correct data instead of patching it on the server side?

Comment: I would be happy to if it is possible. However, to this point I'm still unable to declare that it is a `new Date(` for `mongoose`.

Comment: And can you not simply write something like that: `req.body.startDate.$gte = new Date(req.body.startDate.$gte)`

Comment: No, that provides me this before: `{ startDate: 
   { '$gte': '1111-11-11T00:00:00.000Z',
     '$lte': '2017-08-17T00:00:00.000Z' }}` and after is this: `{ startDate: 
   { '$gte': 1111-11-11T00:00:00.000Z,
     '$lte': 2017-08-17T00:00:00.000Z }}`. The only difference is the location of the quotation marks.

Comment: Have you tried running it against MongoDB, though?

Comment: Indeed I have! As I understand it, `mongoDB` requires `ISODate(` to be literally specified. `mongoose` requires `new Date(` to query `mongoDB` and it masks it to become `ISODate(`. This is the query that would work in `mongoDB shell`: `db.activity.aggregate([
    { $match: {startDate: {$gte: ISODate("1111-11-11T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte: ISODate("2017-08-17T00:00:00.000Z")}}}
])`

Comment: How is `startDate` defined in your schema?

Comment: @JohnnyHK `startDate:    {type: Date,        required: true}`

Comment: It works fine when I try it by simply converting the dates using `new Date("1111-11-11T00:00:00.000Z")` as you show.

Comment: Can you please explain further what you mean by "it works fine"? What did you do that worked correctly? When I do this, I get no results back.

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem and wasn't able to because the date filtering of the $match worked. Can you update your question with a MCVE that includes a sample doc that you expect the query to return?

Comment: @dnickless your solution ended up being correct as I had another error in the program that was causing a failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dnickless said in the comments, I needed to insert

```
req.body.startDate.$gte = new Date(req.body.startDate.$gte)
req.body.startDate.$lte = new Date(req.body.startDate.$lte)
```

Before my `mongoose` query.